# Reference elements for a scroll function inside functional gatsby/react component

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, gatsby

I want to make sticky navigation in Gatsby. I could just make a separate script and reference the element I need to reference, but that seems counter-intuitive for a component pattern.

So I want to reference the Element from inside the component, but I hit a wall. If I use `document.querySelector(".primaryNavigation")` I get `null`, so my question is:

**How do I reference a component element from within a functional component such as below?**

```
export default function PrimaryNavigation() {
  window.onscroll = () => {
    // reference the nav element here
  }
  return (
    <nav className="primaryNavigation">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/blog">Blog</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Comment: you need [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). A combination of `useRef` &  `useEffect` or the class equivalent will do

Comment: @DerekNguyen, perfect! I knew about `ref`, but I needed to dig around a little further and discovered the `current` property. Make an answer of this and I will accept :)

Comment: glad you got it worked out! feel free to post an answer & mark it correct yourself, I had only shared the link to the official docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Derek suggested, I should look into and use [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

I'll show an example of what I did to solve the problem here.

```
export default function Navigation() {
  const nav = React.createRef();

  window.onscroll = function() {
    if(window.pageYOffset > nav.current.offsetTop)
      nav.current.style = "position:fixed;top:0;width:100%";
    else
      nav.current.style = "";
  }

  return (
    <nav ref={nav}>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/whatever">Whatever</Link></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```